# Angular: Template with Context and Get Resulting HTML as String

Tags: angular

I am trying to create dynamic HTML and didn't want to write as strings since its hard to make changes whereas the HTML in the template is easy to modify. I was hoping to find a way to use <ng-template> to write the HTML and fill in the contents by provided template context and then get the resulting HTML as string without rendering the contents in the template.

For example:

test.component.html

```
<ng-template #myTemplate let-context="context">
    <div class='container'>
        <div>
            Title {{context.title}}
        </div>
        <div>
            Description: {{context.description}}
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

test.component.ts

```
@ViewChild('myTemplate ', { read: TemplateRef }) myTemplate?: TemplateRef<any>;

createContents(context: MyObject): string {
    //generate contents from the template based on the given context
    return templateContents;
}
```

Tried using ViewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView() but that embeds the content into the view and couldn't find a way to get the contents as string